# Div containing google maps not closing with Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, block

The Javascript function close() seems not to be working;it should close/hide the div containing a google maps map. In my maps.php file I've got the following:

```
echo"<div class='big_map' id='big_map'></div> <button onclick='displayMap($x,$y)'>Show Map</button>";
echo"<button onclick='close()'>Chiudi</button> ";
```

Then, there is the JS part:

```
<script>
    function close(){
        document.getElementById('big_map').style.display="none";
    }

    function displayMap(lat,long) {
                document.getElementById('big_map').style.display="block";
                initialize(lat,long);
            }
    function initialize(lat,long) {
              // create the map

            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 14,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
              }
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("big_map"),
                                            myOptions);

     }

</script>
```

Comment: Put an alert in your close function... alert('here')... do you see it when you click the button?

Comment: No,I'm not seeing the alert :S

Comment: Just change the name of the `close()` function to `closeMap()`, and it works. http://jsfiddle.net/tkgtcs9q/1/

Comment: Weird. Is close a reserved function name?

Comment: @evilunix Yes it [**is**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_close.asp).

Comment: Oh boy! I did not know that! I'll try it now!

Comment: For reference - other reserved functions names - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp